# Java Swing: Is it possible to use tree table view in java swing?

Tags: java, swing

How could we beautify the table in java swing.

I need a table look like a tree table. Please give me sample code snippet for the same.

Thanks,
Vevek.

Comment: well the answer is "yes, it is possible to make image as a button"

Comment: Now you've changed the question, the answer is still yes. SwingLabs, SwingX library has a JXTreeTable

Comment: can you please share any useful links or a sample code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to extend Jbutton and create your custom button by overriding their methods  or do a little search on the internet and find some good-looking ui library.